# django admin, set choice field length?

Tags: python, django

im trying to set the ChoiceField length in my django form, I used the below:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea, ChoiceField

class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
        models.ChoiceField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
        models.GenericIPAddressField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
    }
    ...
```

and then got the error:

```
  File "/var/www/infternal/sites/admin.py", line 18, in SiteAdmin
    models.ChoiceField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ChoiceField'
```

Does anyone know what i need to alter to change the select/dropdown length?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are defining your form set in the wrong way.
ChoiceField is an attribute of Django forms, not Django models.

Your code should be like this :

```
SOME_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Choice1'),
    ('2', 'Choice2'),
)
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
        models.CharField: {'widget': ChoiceField(choices=SOME_CHOICES,max_length=25})},
        models.GenericIPAddressField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'25'})},
    }
```

Comment: my choices come from foreign keys, what would i do in this instance?

Comment: @AlexW Your current problem was this error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ChoiceField'" Which will be solved by my answer. If you need to ask another query,Please ask it as a different question

Comment: @AlexW if your choices come from foreign keys,calculate them here and put them in place of SOME_CHOICES in "choices=SOME_CHOICES".

Comment: theres an infinite amount of foreign keys. it comes from another model, and i have around 5 of them too

Comment: @AlexW If you need to ask another query,ask it as the different question,because we don't have enough information for your next query  and if my answer solved your current problem,mark it as the right answer,I'll be happy to help in the next question.

Comment: `ChoiceField` is a form field, not a widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could override [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) or [`formfield_for_choicefield`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_choice_field) to alter the field for foreign keys or choice fields respectively. For example:

```
def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    field = super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_choice_field(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    field.widget.attrs['size'] = '25'
    return field
```